# Error building HHVM on Amazon Linux 2014.03 (unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-canonical-system-headers’)

Tags: linux, gcc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hhvm

I'm following the process https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Amazon-Linux-2014.03.

At the time of compilation and installation:

```
[root@ip-172-31-19-191 hhvm]# make
[ 0%] Building CXX object hphp/third_party/folly/CMakeFiles/folly.dir/folly/Demangle.cpp.o
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-canonical-system-headers’
make[2]: *** [hphp/third_party/folly/CMakeFiles/folly.dir/folly/Demangle.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [hphp/third_party/folly/CMakeFiles/folly.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Anyone know why the compiler is not recognizing this command?

Comment: Are you trying to get this running on EB?

Comment: @tslater, EB? What does this mean?

Comment: Do you perform the step `git submodule update --init` ?

Comment: @Sina, No. I did exactly as done in the procedure:
    cd ~ && \
    git clone git://github.com/facebook/hhvm.git && \
    cd hhvm && \
    git checkout HHVM-3.0.1 && \
    git submodule init && \
    git submodule update && \
    export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=`pwd`/.. && \
    cd ..

Comment: I also ran into problems trying to use Amazon Linux, I switched to an EBS backed ubuntu 12.04 instance (m1.small) and it worked great.